# How to number chemical reaction separately from mathematical equations?

Tags: numbering, environments, chemistry

While writing part of my dissertation, I need to number chemical reactions separated from mathematical equations. I checked chemscheme, but it seems not what I'm looking for. I need to numbering of reactions like the equations, with the reaction number appearing on the right.

Do I need to create a custom environment with its own numbering? I don't know how that would be done.

thanks

Comment: Please provide us with an MWE. We do not want to set up the whole thing in order to help you with one line. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6999